# WP_Query date_query - Use unix timestamp?

Tags: wp-query, date-query

I am trying to perform a WP_Query, passing the values for `before` and `after` in the `date_query` as unix timestamps.

This does not seem to work:

```
$args = array(
  'date_query' => array(
    'before' => 1486045020
  )
);
```

I know I could use php's `date()` function to format it to a year, month and day, but I would rather use a unix timestamp to avoid time difference issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution - I used PHP's `date()` function to format it into a ISO 8601 compliant format, so there is no confusion around timezones, etc.

```
$args = array(
  'date_query' => array(
    'before' => date( 'c' , 1486045020 )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the blog database itself to see the exact format Wordpress stores dates in. It doesn't use Unix timestamps. I believe the format is something like `2017-01-31` (YYYY-MM-DD). I think you might have to use the format Wordpress uses, then convert to/from Unix timestamps when you need to.

EDIT, either that or you might be able to use something like `the_date` where you can specify the format.

[Formatting Date and Time](https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time)